# Spark: OutOfMemory despite MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote some piece of code that reads multiple parquet files and caches them for subsequent use. My code looks simplified like this

```
val data = SparkStartup.sqlContext.read.parquet(...)
data.setName(...).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER).collect()
map += data
```

The parquet file are in total about 11g. I config my application by:

```
 val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName(...).setMaster("local[128]")
sparkConfig.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
sparkConfig.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512m");
sparkConfig.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer", "256");
sparkConfig.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0");
sparkConfig.set("spark.driver.memory", "9g");
```

I thought that by using `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`, Spark would spill out to disk if too much memory is used. However, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space errors at

```
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3230)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:155)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:135)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeAscii_slow(Output.java:446)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString(Output.java:306)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeName(DefaultClassResolver.java:105)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:81)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:472)
```

Why is this? I start my application with `-Xmx9g -Dspark.executor.memory=9g -Dspark.executor.cores=3`. For the files that are read before everything crashes, I can see in the SparkUI that a parquet files takes 9x its size when read to memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are calling `collect()` in your driver application.  This returns an `Array` of your data items, which would need to fit into memory.

You should instead work with the `data` RDD and map, reduce, group, etc your large set of data into some desired result, and then `collect()` that smaller amount of data.

Comment: But how else should I cache the data? Caching is only lazy and called when a collect is performed, right? And then: Why doesn't it spill out to disk?

Comment: No, not when a collect() is called.  collect converts your data into an Array which is returned to your driver.  You can call cache() and then count() on your RDD and that will cause it to be cached in memory.

Comment: I added the `spark.rdd.compress` option and now I don't seem to get any out of memory erros and it starts spilling out to disk. But I can't tell you why this is suddenly is.